# my header div cant attach with container

Tags: html, css

i have 3 div header  center and footer in one container div, when i assign width and height all of 3 div, they were ok and working fine but when i put h1 heading and paragraphs tag in header div then header div changed his old position and moved far away from container, so i want to join/attach my header div with container top border, here is my code which is not working

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Inspiration For All By Fame Team</h1>
        <p style="color:white;">On This Blog You Can Read Many Stories Which Will Inspire You And Motivate You</p>
    </div>
    <div id="center"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    background-color:#D8FFA8;
}

#container{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    width:80%;
    height:800px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:thick;
    border-color:#878787;
    border-radius:20px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#header{
    background-color:blue;
    width:100%;
    height:150px; 
    position:relative;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 auto;
    border-top-left-radius:15px;
    border-top-right-radius:15px;
}
```

My image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bNEF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adding `margin` and `padding` 0 to all the elements:

```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  body {
    background-color: #D8FFA8;
  }
  #container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 80%;
    height: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thick;
    border-color: #878787;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #header {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Inspiration For All</title>
</head>

<body>`
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1>Inspiration For All By Fame Team</h1>
      <p style="color:white;">On This Blog You Can Read Many Stories Which Will Inspire You And Motivate You</p>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: but with this code containe div also attached with body/browser, i just want my header div(blue color div) attach with container div

Comment: Didn't get you... can you provide a snap what exactly you want?

Comment: am not able to upload snap, i want just my header div attached with border of container div, not container div attached with body tag's border

Comment: body doesn't have border but your container does